# Heroku create new

Tags: java, ubuntu, heroku, deployment, playframework

`heroku create -s play` ?

/opt/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:93: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt/play-2.2.3 in PATH, mode 040777

! Heroku client internal error.

! Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com

! Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

```
Error:       uninitialized constant Heroku::Command::RestClient (NameError)
Backtrace:   /opt/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:225:in `rescue in run'
             /opt/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:271:in `run'
             /opt/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:37:in `start'
             /opt/heroku/bin/heroku:17:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku create
Version:     heroku-gem/3.9.4 (i686-linux) ruby/2.1.2
```

How to fix this ... thankyou very mutch

Comment: Are you logged in Heroku? Try `heroku login` before `heroku create`. If it can't help, try to re-install Heroku Toolbelt.

Comment: in the first time .. no but I do this :

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm requirements

after i can login


but heroku create never work